# GitLab CI - CI script fail to run on Merge Request event

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I have a GitLab CI script that works perfectly on local commits. However when doing a merge request the CI fail to initiate and fail with the message: "Unable to create pipeline".

I'm using Gitlab CE 15.11.8 on-premise.

Here is the .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
stages:
  - build_sw
  - build_algo
  - report
  - cppcheck


build-test:
  stage: build_sw
  tags: 
    - sw-team-3080
  script:
    - echo "Compile & Test"
    - mkdir build && cd build
    - cmake ..
    - make -j$((`nproc`-2))
    - ./unittest
    
algo-analysis-job:
  stage: build_algo
  tags:
    - DockerSlave_3080
  image: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#  allow_failure: true    # Keep running 
  needs:
    - build-test
  script:
    - rm -rvf $ALGO_RESULTS || exit 0
    - ./python test.py

  allow_failure: true
  after_script: 
    - echo "Job Status Code is *** $CI_JOB_STATUS ***"
    - echo "" > /tmp/job-ci-status.tmp
    - |- 
          if [[ $CI_JOB_STATUS == "failed" ]]; then echo "FAIL" >> /tmp/job-ci-status.tmp
          fi
          if [[ $CI_JOB_STATUS == "success" ]]; then echo "PASS" >> /tmp/job-ci-status.tmp
          fi
    
report:
  stage: report
  tags: 
    - sw-team-3080
  needs:
    - build-test
    - algo-analysis-job
  script:
    - zip -r $CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH.zip $ALGO_RESULTS
  artifacts:
    paths:
        - $CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH.zip
    expire_in: 2 week
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null

cppcheck-code-quality:
  stage: cppcheck
  tags:
    - doxy-server
  script:
    - echo "Running CPPTEST on code to produce GitLab Code Quality"
    - cppcheck --xml --enable=warning --library=googletest . 2> cppcheck_out.xml
    - python -m cppcheck_codequality --input-file=cppcheck_out.xml --output-file=cppcheck.json
  artifacts:
    reports:
      codequality: cppcheck.json
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null
```

I tried to run it on regular commit - It works perfectly - All jobs completed successfully.
I tried to do a merge request , and the pipeline failed (No jobs started).

I managed to solve the issue by adding the 'rules' section to each job that 'report' job was depend on like that:

````
build-test:
  stage: build_sw
  tags: 
    - sw-team-3080
  script:
    - echo "Compile & Test"
    - mkdir build && cd build
    - cmake ..
    - make -j$((`nproc`-2))
    - ./unittest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null 
    ```
````

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by adding the 'rules' section to each job that 'report' job was depend on like that:
`  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null `